# R - Replace all NA's in a dataframe with NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I replace all '`NA`' with '`NULL`' in an `R` dataframe without specifying column names?
I found `replace_na` function from `tidyr` which has an example as:

```
# Replace NAs in a data frame
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"))
df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "unknown"))
```

but my table has more than 10 columns and it could change. Can't specify column names like in the example above.

Comment: What do you mean by `'NULL'`? If you mean the string `'NULL'`, then you'll need to first convert your numeric columns to `character` class, then it's as simple as `df[is.na(df)] <- "NULL"`. If you want the actual `NULL`, then that doesn't really work. `NULL` has 0-length, so it can't fill a spot in a data frame. `c(1, 2, NULL)` is the same as `c(1, 2)` - `NULL` *isn't there*.

Comment: good point. I meant string 'NULL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R way to do this:

`apply(df, 2, function(x) { x[ is.na(x) ] <- 'NULL'; x})`

Note that you can't really insert `NULL` as it has length 0, you can insert: `''` or `NA`

Comment: This will return a matrix, not a data.frame, and if there are a mix of character and numeric columns the numeric columns will be coerced to character even if they don't have any NA's because `apply` converts its first argument to a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches. One assuming you want 0 in numeric columns and "unknown" in character, and one assuming you want 'NULL' independent of column type.

Approach 1:

```r
library(tidyr); library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"))
df %>% 
    mutate(
        across(where(is.numeric), replace_na, 0),
        across(where(is.character), replace_na, "unknown")
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       x y      
#>   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1 a      
#> 2     2 unknown
#> 3     0 b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Approach 2:

```r
library(tidyr); library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"))
df %>% 
    mutate(
        across(everything(), ~ if(anyNA(.)) replace_na(as.character(.), 'NULL'))
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     a    
#> 2 2     NULL 
#> 3 NULL  b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>